# Windows service cannot attach to process

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows service.For debugging that windows service I tried to attach it to the process.but I cannot find the process from "attach to process" in visualstudio2010. But I can see the windows service is running in "**services.msc**".How can I attach the process?Is there any other way to debug the windows service?Thanks in advance...

Comment: If the service is running it *should* show up as its own executable.  You would likely need to tick "show processes from other users/sessions" and other such options to see a complete list of processes.  On a side note, debugging Windows Services is notoriously difficult in this way.  I recommend having a console application in the same solution which uses the same code (or even references the Windows Service project and calls its methods directly), that generally covers most debugging needs.

Comment: Hi David thanks for your reply.I have ticked "Show processes from other users/sessions".Even though it doesn't show on the process list.But I can seen from the "servises.msc" that the process is running..

Comment: @David can you please tell me how to add a reference to the windows service from a console application..

Comment: Is the Service name different than the .exe name?  When you attach to process, you should see the .exe name.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes the service name is different from .exe name.But I cannot find none of them  from the process list.

Answer (score 0):

in the 'attach to process', select option 'show processes from all user'.